# sum column until blank cell total in different column

Tags: excel, sum

I need a sum of transactions to show up in a specific cell in order to use it to import the invoices. 
I have a macro to insert a blank row between differing accounts and now i need a formula to sum that specific accounts transactions and place to total in column N.

[image]

Currently I have

```
=IF(F1="",SUM(F2:INDEX(F2:$F$600,MATCH(TRUE,(F3:$F$600=""),0))),"")
```

as the formula in N1. I'm using Excel 2007 and I'm not sure if that is the reason the index advise on other posts isn't working.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Should the formula in N5 be the total of F2:F4 or F6:F9?

Comment: Also with the formula you are using, it needs to be array entered with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this non array formula in N1 put:

```
=IF(F1="",SUMIF(B:B,B2,F:F),"")
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: IF this worked for you, please click the check mark by the answer, this will mark this question as answered and remove it from the unanswered queue